# JSON to Hold Course, Student, and Assignment Data

Tags: java, json

I am trying to use JSON to contain data related to a class/course.  The idea is that there are 40 classes/courses and that each class/course contains 50 students, and each student has 100 assignments.  Below is what I've figured out so far.  How can I modify it to hold all the gradebook data, as listed above?

```
public void x(){

        JSONObject courseJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray courseJSONArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject studentJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray studentJSONArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject assignmentJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray assignmentJSONArray = new JSONArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){

            courseJSONObject.put("course name", course.getName());
            courseJSONObject.put("course teacher", course.getTeacher());

            courseJSONArray.put(courseJSONObject);

            courseJSONObject = new JSONObject();

            for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++){

                studentJSONObject.put("student name", course.student.getName());
                studentJSONObject.put("student id", course.student.getid());
                studentJSONObject.put("student final grade",  
                    course.student.getfinalgrade());

                studentJSONArray.put(studentJSONObject);

                studentJSONObject = new JSONObject();

                for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++){

                    assignmentJSONObject.put("assignment name", getAssignmentName());
                    assignmentJSONObject.put("category", getAssignmentCategory());
                    assignmentJSONObject.put("date", getAssignmentDate());
                    assignmentJSONObject.put("grade", 
                        course.student.getAssignmentGrade());

                    assignmentJSONArray.put(assignmentJSONArray);

                    assignmentJSONObject = new JSONObject();

                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to have this [structure](http://pastebin.com/Gif6Y4eB)?

Comment: Yes, but there has to be multiple courses, and for each course there are multiple students, and for each student there are multiple assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray courses = new JSONArray();
for(int c = 0; i < 40; c++) {
    JSONObject course = new JSONObject();
    // Add course details
    JSONArray students = new JSONArray();
    for(int s = 0; s < 50; s++) {
        JSONObject student = new JSONObject();
        // Add Student details
        JSONArray assignments = new JSONArray();
        for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
            JSONObject assignment = new JSONObject();
            // Add assignment details
            assignments.put( assignment );
        }
        student.put( "assignments", assignments );
        students.put( student )
    }
    course.put( "students", students );
    courses.put( course );
}
```

Comment: I want to thank you for your help.  I'm going to fill in the missing code and look at it closely to figure out if it will work or if I have any questions.  I'll get back to you to by midday tomorrow. I've been working on this for a while, so I hope that this does it.

Comment: I looked it over pretty well.  This definitely helps me to move forward.